# Python number in range

Tags: python

I can't seem to understand why the function fix_teen returns 13 and not 0.

As we have r in the range of 13-19, we check if n in r, it even returns "True" when outside the if/else function.
I also tried it this way `if 13 <= n <= 19:` and the issue still persists.

```
def fix_teen(n):
  r = range(13,19)
  
  if n in r :
    return n == 0
  
  elif n == 15 or n ==16:
    return n

  else :
    return n

  
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  print(fix_teen(a))
  print(fix_teen(b))
  print(fix_teen(c))

  print(a+b+c)
  

no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1)
```

Comment: This code: `if n in r : return n == 0` will return a boolean if called, watch out of that

Comment: The printed results are `2`, `False`, `1`, `16`, the function `fix_teen` cannot return `13`. The condition in `elif` can never be true, either.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the meaning of "function fix_teen returns 13"?

Answer (score -1):

The bit of code below, returns the result of an equality operator (n == 0).

```
 if n in r :
     return n == 0
```

If you want to return 0 if the n is in the range, simply return 0:

```
if n in r:
   return 0
```